# application.properties has not been overwritten by ConfigMap Spring Boot with Helm

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I'm trying to connect my Spring Boot application 'Onboarding' with a PostgreSQL database, both inside Minikube.

The connection properties inside my Onboarding *application.properties* are as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/restaurant-dev
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=onboarding
spring.datasource.username= xxx
spring.datasource.password= xxx
```

on the other hand, the connection properties inside my *values.yaml* are like this:

```
configMap:
  name: onboarding-config
  url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres.restaurant-dev:5432;databaseName=restaurant-dev
  schema: onboarding

secrets:
  name: "onboarding-secrets"
  dbserver:
    password: xxx
    username: xxx
```

However, when I open the Onboarding Pod logs, the application is trying to connect using the *application.properties* data:

```
2023-08-10T21:36:06.282+0000 DEBUG isolateInternalQueries..........false
2023-08-10T21:36:06.282+0000 DEBUG jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/restaurant-dev
2023-08-10T21:36:06.282+0000 DEBUG keepaliveTime...................0
2023-08-10T21:36:06.282+0000 DEBUG leakDetectionThreshold..........0
2023-08-10T21:36:06.282+0000 DEBUG maxLifetime.....................1800000

2023-08-10T21:36:06.326+0000 DEBUG HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2023-08-10T21:36:06.326+0000 DEBUG HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I verified if the *deployment.yaml* was constructed correctly by running:

`kubectl get deploy onboarding -n restaurant-dev -o yaml`

and it seems correct:

```
   spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: onboarding-config
        - secretRef:
            name: onboarding-secrets
        image: restaurant/onboarding:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: onboarding
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 900m
            memory: 256Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Spring Boot Apps should override properties with the config maps, right?

This is how the configMap template looks:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.configMap.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  spring.datasource.url: "{{ .Values.configMap.url }}"
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema: "{{ .Values.configMap.schema }}"
```

and the secrets template:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  POSTGRES_USER: {{ .Values.secrets.dbserver.password | b64enc }}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: {{ .Values.secrets.dbserver.username | b64enc }}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secrets.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: You're just setting the values from your configmap as env variables so the question is if your spring boot application actually reads those env vars and gives them priority over what it loaded from file.There's a relatively extensive (even though its a little dated) blog from red hat about working with spring boot and kubernetes config maps that explains the difference https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/03/configuring-spring-boot-kubernetes-configmap#

Comment: Rick, I couldn't understand exactly which part of the article can help me. The article doesn't show any changes inside the application, although there's a section titled 'Modifying GreeterController', the code remains the same as the one at the beginning of the article. Maybe there's an error... The only difference I saw from what I did is that it sets the variables within the `containers: - env:` structure. So, did you mean that I have to place all my Hibernate/JPA properties in that structure?